Magento 2 : JS Errors when dealing with Checkout
I use magento 2.2.5. When I imported files from an existing website to another server on plesk. Problem is, after deploying, upgrading and compiling correctly, on checkout I get a message that says "invalid shipping information, check input value". When i open console it show me following error.

